# Verilog debug 8-1 Multiplexer by gates

Tags: verilog

I need create 8*1 multiplexer by 2-1 multiplexer.
At this time, my code can work. However, the output is incorrect.
And the wires O_0.O_1,O_2,O_3 can work correctly.
When the 2-1 multiplexer read the selector [1] and [2], it does not change.
The output is between I0 AND I1.
Can you help me with the problem? Or just tell me where the mistake is?

*This is not italic* 
`

```
module MUX_8_1 (i0 ,i1 ,i2 ,i3 ,i4 ,i5 ,i6 ,i7 , selectors , o_8 );
input  [31:0] i0 ,i1 ,i2 ,i3 ,i4 ,i5 ,i6 ,i7;
input  [2:0]  selectors ;
output [31:0] o_8 ;
wire     [31:0] o_0;
wire     [31:0] o_1;
wire     [31:0] o_2;
wire     [31:0] o_3;
wire     [31:0] o_4;
wire     [31:0] o_5;    

MUX_2_1 M1(.i0 (i0),    .i1 (i1),     .sel (selectors[0]),.o (o_0));
MUX_2_1 M2(.i0 (i2),    .i1 (i3),     .sel (selectors[0]),.o (o_1));
MUX_2_1 M3(.i0 (i4),    .i1 (i5),     .sel (selectors[0]),.o (o_2));
MUX_2_1 M4(.i0 (i6),    .i1 (i7),     .sel (selectors[0]),.o (o_3));


MUX_2_1 M5(.i0 (o_0),   .i1 (o_1),    .sel (selectors[1]),.o (o_4));
MUX_2_1 M6(.i0 (o_2),   .i1 (o_3),    .sel (selectors[1]),.o (o_5));
MUX_2_1 M7(.i0 (o_4),   .i1 (o_5),    .sel (selectors[2]),.o (o_8));

endmodule

module MUX_2_1 (i0 ,i1 ,sel ,o);
input  [31:0] i0 ,i1;
input   sel ;
output [31:0] o;

assign #19  o  = (i0 & (~sel)) |  (i1 &   sel);
endmodule`
```

*This is not italic*

```
module MUX_8_1_TB;

// Inputs
reg [31:0] i0;
reg [31:0] i1;
reg [31:0] i2;
reg [31:0] i3;
reg [31:0] i4;
reg [31:0] i5;
reg [31:0] i6;
reg [31:0] i7;
reg [2:0] selectors;

// Outputs
wire [31:0]o_8;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
MUX_8_1 uut (
    .i0(i0), 
    .i1(i1), 
    .i2(i2), 
    .i3(i3), 
    .i4(i4), 
    .i5(i5), 
    .i6(i6), 
    .i7(i7), 
    .selectors(selectors), 
    .o_8(o_8)
);

initial begin

    i0 = 32'b1000;
    i1 = 32'b1001; 
    i2 = 32'b1010; 
    i3 = 32'b1011; 
    i4 = 32'b1100; 
    i5 = 32'b1101; 
    i6 = 32'b1110; 
    i7 = 32'b1111; 

    selectors = 3'b000;#100;
    selectors = 3'b001;#100;
    selectors = 3'b010;#100;
    selectors = 3'b011;#100;
    selectors = 3'b100;#100;
    selectors = 3'b101;#100;
    selectors = 3'b110;#100;
    selectors = 3'b111;#100;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, assign statement in the MUX_2_1 is not proper.

You have 2 options to rectify it.

**1st Option**

You can use ternary operator (which is more preferable, as per my opinion)

```
assign o = (sel) ? (i1) : (i0);
```

**2nd Option**

It seems that, you wrote this code, by considering the actual gate level schematic or netlist of the 2*1 mux.

But to mimic, the actual gate level design, you should consider ANDing of the individual bits of the i0, i1 nets.

So your code may look like this :

```
assign o[0] = (i0[0] & ~sel) | (i1[0] & sel);
assign o[1] = (i0[1] & ~sel) | (i1[1] & sel);
assign o[2] = (i0[2] & ~sel) | (i1[2] & sel);
// Similarly for all 32 bits
assign o[31] = (i0[31] & ~sel) | (i1[31] & sel);
```

Now, you may wonder that, you need to copy same statement 32 times!!!!.

So you have an alternative for this :

```
genvar c;
generate
  for (c = 0; c < 32; c = c + 1) 
    begin: test
      assign o[c] = (i0[c] & ~sel) | (i1[c] & sel);
    end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

Its your 2:1 Mux logic seems to be flawed. Try

```
assign o = (sel) ? i1 : i0;
```